# Как поставить капчу на форму сайта?

Tags: captcha

На сайте нужна капча от спам ботов на форме отправления данных. Я не знаю как её поставить помогите "-"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую использовать вам reCAPTCHA(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/) от гугла.

1. Для начала нам нужен серийный ключ от Google, ради которого переходим по первой ссылке и регистрируемся, после чего привязываем сайт.
2. Далее влезаем в HTML код, где ищем , перед которым размещаем небольшой java-скрипт:

```js
<script src=’https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js’></script>
```

3. Находим интересующую вас форму и вписываем код следующего содержания:

Очевидно, что на месте нулей должен располагаться серийный ключ, полученный после прохождения регистрации и привязки. В конечном итоге, в форме «комментария» должно получиться нечто подобное:

```html
<head>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="http://названиевашегосайта/comm.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
    <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Номер" />
    <textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Комментарий:" />
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="0000000000000000000000" style="margin-bottom:1em";></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="rss-button" />
  </form>
</body>
```

5- И всё должно работать.

Если же вы хотите добавить капчу на PHP-страницу, то вам необходимо пройти через ещё один пункт.

1. Переходим к работе над формой – в нашем примере это /comm.php, к которому нужно добавить скрипт:

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

и после тега <?php:

```js
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) {
  $secret = '0000000000000000000000';
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  $rsp = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response&remoteip=$ip");
  $arr = json_decode($rsp, TRUE);
  if ($arr['success']) {
    ...
  }
}
```

В этом коде, как и в предыдущем, необходимо изменить нолики в значении $secret на код секретного ключа, только в данном случае вам нужно вписывать уже другой — тот, что отмечен грифом «*secret».

Ссылки, если я не понятно объяснил: https://techrocks.ru/2019/10/19/adding-captcha-to-a-website/, сам сайт: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/

Ps(ответ отуда)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Пользуйтесь, удачи

Comment: Если хотите изменить каптчу  то можно добавить и со других сервисов но гугл самый проверенный

Comment: И ещё никогда не делайте каптчу на фронтенде